# postgres sql view with a col for each identifier

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table for observations, with a "time", "value" and "identifier" column. The time column holds the time stamp of the values, the identifier holds the parameter names.

How can I create a view with a separate column for each parameter and a row for each time stamp? There will be empty grids, because not all parameters are measured each time.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Can we count on having a fix list of parameters?